# Log messages parser

Tags: parsing, haskell

I've been studying Haskell for some time, but I have never used it for real. So, I started following the [CIS 194 Course from UPenn](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/). I resolved the [second homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/02-ADTs.pdf) but I'm not fully satisfied with the parser I came up with. I think it's way too verbose and I don't like the way the message string is passed around. I am also not sure if the code is being idiomatic.

Is it following Haskell standards and being idiomatic?

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module LogAnalysis where

import Log
import Text.Read

getErrorSeverity :: Maybe Int -> Maybe MessageType
getErrorSeverity (Just c) = Just (Error c)
getErrorSeverity _        = Nothing

parseMessageType :: String -> Maybe MessageType
parseMessageType "" = Nothing
parseMessageType m = case words m of
    "I":_   -> Just Info
    "W":_   -> Just Warning
    "E":l:_ -> getErrorSeverity (readMaybe l)
    _       -> Nothing

parseTimeStamp :: String -> Maybe TimeStamp
parseTimeStamp m = case words m of
    "E":_:s:_ -> readMaybe s
    "I":s:_   -> readMaybe s
    "W":s:_   -> readMaybe s
    _         -> Nothing

parseLogContent :: String -> Maybe String
parseLogContent m = case words m of
    "E":_:_:r -> Just (unwords r)
    _:_:r     -> Just (unwords r)
    _         -> Nothing

parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage "" = Unknown ""
parseMessage m = case (parseMessageType m, parseTimeStamp m, parseLogContent m) of
    (Just t, Just ts, Just c) -> LogMessage t ts c
    _      -> Unknown m
```

Comment: Just for inspiration - my suboptimal but shorter solution had been, at the time, http://lpaste.net/151248

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: *I assume you want to write confident idiomatic Haskell regardless if an assignment guarantees a perfect log file format. Because, in the real world of software development there are no such guarantees. Better to build the habit now while you're learning rather than later when you're pressed to meet a deadline.*

In light of my disclaimer, I must disagree with the answer you accepted. It is bad advice to say that one should avoid `Maybe`. In fact, I would argue that the code you presented is better than the code you accepted as the answer.

Why?

The `parseMessage` you wrote is a total function as opposed to a partial function. Let's see what others have to say about this:

- [Partial functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Partial_functions)
- [Avoiding partial functions](https://wiki.haskell.org/Avoiding_partial_functions)
- [Are your functions total?](http://aadrake.com/are-your-functions-total.html)

Now that we agree on the use of total functions let's try to refactor the code while keeping `parseMessage` a total function.

There are two main ways `parseMessage` can fail to parse a message:

1. The log line isn't in the info, warning or error format.
2. The timestamp or severity isn't given as an integer.

The 1st problem we can handle via pattern matching:

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage m =
  case (words m) of
    "I":t:ws   -> undefined
    "W":t:ws   -> undefined
    "E":s:t:ws -> undefined
    _          -> Unknown m
```

The 2nd problem we can isolate as follows:

```
parseInt :: String -> Maybe Int
parseInt s =
  case (reads s :: [(Int, String)]) of
    [(n, "")] -> Just n
    _         -> Nothing
```

Note the use of `Maybe` to explicitly declare that this function may fail to parse an `Int`. It is a total function.

To learn more about `reads` check out [this](https://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/reads.xhtml) wonderful article.

Let's now make a bold assumption so that we don't have to deal with `Maybe` explicitly in our code.

Let's assume we always have an `Int` when it is needed. For e.g. when we need the timestamp as an `Int` let's assume we have it.

Doing so allows us to write the following functions:

```
info c t    = LogMessage Info t c
warning c t = LogMessage Warning t c
err c s t   = LogMessage (Error s) t c
```

Now, this doesn't quite work:

```
info (unwords ws) (parseInt t)
```

Because `parseInt` returns `Maybe Int` and `info` only accepts an `Int` as its 2nd argument. What we really need is:

```
asInfo :: String -> Maybe Int -> Maybe LogMessage
asInfo _ Nothing -> Nothing
asInfo c (Just t) -> Just (info c t)
```

Well, that is what `liftA` and `liftA2` can do for us:

```
asInfo c    = liftA $ info c
asWarning c = liftA $ warning c
asErr c     = liftA2 $ err c
```

Finally, when we use `asInfo (unwords ws) (parseInt t)` we don't want to get back `Nothing` in the case of a failure. We really want to return `Unknown m`. We can use `maybe` for that:

```
maybe (Unknown m) id (asInfo (unwords ws) (parseInt t))
```

Putting everything together we get:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA, liftA2)

parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage m =
  case (words m) of
    "I":t:ws   -> try $ asI (unwords ws) $ parseInt t
    "W":t:ws   -> try $ asW (unwords ws) $ parseInt t
    "E":s:t:ws -> try $ asE (unwords ws) (parseInt s) $ parseInt t
    _          -> u
  where
    try = maybe u id

    asI c = liftA $ i c
    asW c = liftA $ w c
    asE c = liftA2 $ e c

    i c t   = LogMessage Info t c
    w c t   = LogMessage Warning t c
    e c s t = LogMessage (Error s) t c
    u       = Unknown m

parseInt :: String -> Maybe Int
parseInt s =
  case (reads s :: [(Int, String)]) of
    [(n, "")] -> Just n
    _         -> Nothing
```

Note how the main part of the code captures the essence of the problem we're trying to solve while we still get to explicitly handle any errors that may occur and remain confident about our code.

```
case (words m) of
    "I":t:ws   -> try $ asI (unwords ws) $ parseInt t
    "W":t:ws   -> try $ asW (unwords ws) $ parseInt t
    "E":s:t:ws -> try $ asE (unwords ws) (parseInt s) $ parseInt t
    _          -> u
```

That I believe is the beauty of Haskell.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks for the bit of education :) Please feel warmly invited to the [2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595), the main chatroom of Code Review for a chat. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

First of all let me stress that I am only doing basic stuff in haskell right now. This means you should take my advice with more than just a grain of salt.
`</disclaimer>`

#### Redundant imports

The first thing that ghci warned me about was: "The `import Text.Read` is redundant, [..]". Let's get rid of that, we won't need it

#### Avoid Maybe

All the functions you declared here (or almost all that is) use one or multiple `Maybe`s. Maybe makes you have to jump through hoops to get to your data when it's not necessary, especially since the assignment **guarantees** a specific log format, that doesn't have room for any `Maybe`. After removing all the `Maybe`s I got following code:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
module LogAnalysis where

import Log

getErrorSeverity :: Int -> MessageType
getErrorSeverity c = Error c

parseMessageType :: String -> MessageType
parseMessageType m = case words m of
    "I":_   -> Info
    "W":_   -> Warning
    "E":l:_ -> getErrorSeverity (read l)

parseTimeStamp :: String -> TimeStamp
parseTimeStamp m = case words m of
    "E":_:s:_ -> read s
    "I":s:_   -> read s
    "W":s:_   -> read s

parseLogContent :: String -> String
parseLogContent m = case words m of
    "E":_:_:r -> unwords r
    _:_:r     -> unwords r

parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage "" = Unknown ""
parseMessage m = case (parseMessageType m, parseTimeStamp m, parseLogContent m) of
    (t, ts, c) -> LogMessage t ts c
    _      -> Unknown m
```

Loading this into ghci gets me a few warnings about non-exhaustive patterns, but that shouldn't be a problem as long as the logfiles adhere to the given spec :)

#### Patterns are power

What you're doing here is pattern matching over and over and over. You throw away most of the patterns you match. Repeat after me: **Patterns are power**

The following 6 lines do the whole work of all the other functions you have there:

```
parseMessage :: String -> LogMessage
parseMessage "" = Unknown ""
parseMessage m = case words m of
    "E":s:t:r -> LogMessage (Error $ read s) (read t) (unwords r)
    "W":t:r -> LogMessage Warning (read t) (unwords r)
    "I":t:r -> LogMessage Info (read t) (unwords r)
    _ -> Unknown m
```

Last but not least you could try to extract the duplication around `(read t) (unwords r)`, but I'd say that's not necessary

Comment: Thanks for the review. I'm using the Maybes to avoid runtime errors with messages like "E asd asdasd some string instead of numbers". It occurst because "read" is failing to convert "asd" to an integer value. I think it should parse to __Unknown "asd asdasd some string instead of numbers"__ instead of throwing an exception. But your solution is really clean though, I like that!

Comment: @LucasKreutz the way I understood the assignment, the Logfile is guaranteed to not have lines resulting in such errors. You are correct wrt. that Maybe would avoid this problem, but I think it's worrying too much over something that shouldn't happen