# CIS 194 Homework 2: Parsing an error log

Tags: beginner, parsing, haskell, homework, logging

Here is another reference solution, that I discovered after writing my own:

> https://insight.io/github.com/beloglazov/haskell-course/blob/HEAD/hw2.hs

I am following [this](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/lectures.html) lecture course as a complete beginner to Haskell. As there is no one to check my solutions to the homework assignments, I am posting here.

Until now, the lecture notes include: boolean logic, functions, tuples, lists, algebraic types, pattern matching, Prelude, case expressions, recursive data types.

The task is to parse this (and similar) error log files:

```
I 6 Completed armadillo processing
I 1 Nothing to report
I 4 Everything normal
I 11 Initiating self-destruct sequence
E 70 3 Way too many pickles
E 65 8 Bad pickle-flange interaction detected
W 5 Flange is due for a check-up
I 7 Out for lunch, back in two time steps
E 20 2 Too many pickles
I 9 Back from lunch
E 99 10 Flange failed!
```

The meaning of those lines can be glimpsed in the provided together with the homework file Log.hs:

```
module Log where

import Control.Applicative

data MessageType = Info
                 | Warning
                 | Error Int
  deriving (Show, Eq)

type TimeStamp = Int

data LogMessage = LogMessage MessageType TimeStamp String
                | Unknown String
  deriving (Show, Eq)

data MessageTree = Leaf
                 | Node MessageTree LogMessage MessageTree
  deriving (Show, Eq)

-- | @testParse p n f@ tests the log file parser @p@ by running it
--   on the first @n@ lines of file @f@.
testParse :: (String -> [LogMessage])
          -> Int
          -> FilePath
          -> IO [LogMessage]
testParse parse n file = take n . parse <$> readFile file

 -- | @testWhatWentWrong p w f@ tests the log file parser @p@ and
--   warning message extractor @w@ by running them on the log file
--   @f@.
testWhatWentWrong :: (String -> [LogMessage])
                  -> ([LogMessage] -> [String])
                  -> FilePath
                  -> IO [String]
testWhatWentWrong parse whatWentWrong file
  = whatWentWrong . parse <$> readFile file
```

My solution:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

module Main where

import Log as L

-- Skip 'n' words and interpret the next one as a number.
wordsToNum :: String -> Int -> Int
wordsToNum s n = read ((words s) !! n)

-- Return the tail of a string.
dropWords :: String -> Int -> String
dropWords s n = unwords ( drop n (words s))

-- Convert a line from the sample log into an object of type L.LogMessage.
parseMessage :: String -> L.LogMessage
parseMessage [] = L.Unknown ""
parseMessage p@(x:_) = case x of
                        'E' -> L.LogMessage (L.Error (wordsToNum p 1)) (wordsToNum p 2) (dropWords p 3)
                        'W' -> L.LogMessage L.Warning                  (wordsToNum p 1) (dropWords p 2)
                        'I' -> L.LogMessage L.Info                     (wordsToNum p 1) (dropWords p 2) 
                        _   -> L.Unknown p

-- Parse a whole logfile.
parse :: String -> [LogMessage]
parse s = map parseMessage (lines s)

-- Insert a L.LogMessage into a sorted L.MessageTree.
insert :: L.LogMessage -> L.MessageTree -> L.MessageTree
insert (L.Unknown _) t = t
insert m (L.Leaf) = L.Node Leaf m Leaf
insert m@(L.LogMessage _ ts1 _)
       (L.Node lhs (L.LogMessage _ ts2 _) rhs) 
         = case ts1 > ts2 of
             True -> insert m rhs
             _    -> insert m lhs
insert _ _ = L.Leaf  -- error, what do we do now?


-- Construct tree sorted by timestamp.
build :: [L.LogMessage] -> L.MessageTree
build [] = L.Leaf
build (m:l) = insert m (build l) 

-- Flatten the tree into a sorted list.
inOrder :: L.MessageTree -> [L.LogMessage]
inOrder (L.Leaf) = []
inOrder (L.Node lhs m rhs) = inOrder lhs ++ [m] ++ inOrder rhs

-- Sort by increasing timestamp.
sort :: [L.LogMessage] -> [L.LogMessage]
sort l = inOrder (build l)

-- Remove massages, that are not error with severity >= 50.
filterList :: [L.LogMessage] -> [L.LogMessage]
filterList [] = []
filterList (m@(L.LogMessage (Error e) _ _):l) = case e >= 50 of
                                                  True -> [m] ++ filterList l
                                                  _    -> filterList l 
filterList (_:l) = filterList l

toString :: [L.LogMessage] -> [String]
toString [] = []
toString (m:l) = [show m] ++ toString l

-- Extracts Error messages with severity >= 50 from an _unsorted_ list.
whatWentWrong :: [L.LogMessage] -> [String]
whatWentWrong [] = []
whatWentWrong l = toString (filterList (sort l))

main :: IO()
main = do
         print (parseMessage "E 2 562 help help")
         print (parseMessage "I 29 la la la")
         print (parseMessage "This is not in the right format")

         _ <- L.testParse parse 10 "./sample.log" 

         a <- L.testWhatWentWrong parse whatWentWrong "./sample.log"
         print (unlines a)
```

Comment: related question (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117351/37660)

Comment: It's been more than a year. Do you want to review your own code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simplifications for the pattern usage you currently have:

The pattern in `parseMessage` can be extended so you don't need to explicitly use `dropWords`. That only works if you change the signature to something based on words instead of the whole line, though.

That is the first thing you may want to adjust. As it now stands you're doing a lot of work with "splitting and reassembling" strings.
In the spirit of avoiding unnecessary work, you should only do that once.

Now assuming your `parseMessage` were to work off a "splitted" string, you could instead have:

```hs
parseMessage :: [String] -> L.LogMessage
parseMessage "E":e:t:m = L.LogMessage (L.Error (read e)) (read t) (unwords m)
parseMessage "W":t:m = L.LogMessage L.Warning (read t) (unwords m)
parseMessage "I":t:m = L.LogMessage L.Info (read t) (unwords m)
parseMessage p = L.Unknown (unwords p)
```

Note that `unwords` already correctly handles the case of `p = []`

This allows you to completely drop the helpers `dropWords` and `wordsToNum`.

---

Additional minor simplifications, spoilers hide the full solution ;)

- `parse` could be written as a function composition to avoid specifying the parameter `s`.

> `parse = (map parseMessage) . lines`

- `build` is commonly known in functional programming as a `fold`. It collapses a list into a single element.
  In this case, the fold is "right-associative", so the whole thing can be reformulated with `foldr`:

> `build = foldr insert Leaf`

Here's a bit of an explanation why this works:

> Let's write this a bit more ... verbosely: `build ms = foldr insert Leaf ms`. What basically happens here is that you give a neutral or starter element (`Leaf`) and `insert` is repeatedly called in the following way:
>
>  `` (m1 `insert` (m2 `insert` (... (mn `insert` Leaf)))) ``

---

Note  that there is a huge bug in how `insert` works. As it stands, `insert` will only ever return a tree with a single `Node` in it. To understand why you need to reevaluate what `insert` does and how mutability works in haskell (hint: it doesn't).

Sidenote here: you can simplify `insert` a bit with an `if .. then .. else ..`. You should call insert a few times and see what happens with the LogMessage that has the timestamp `t2`.

---

If you weren't probably forced to use a tree for sorting `sort` would be much easier to write in terms of `Data.List.sortBy`.

Similarly, `filterList` also already exists in the form of `filter`:

> `filterList = filter (\(L.LogMessage (Error e) _ _) -> e >= 50)`
>  Note that this particular piece is untested

An additional simplification is noticing that `toString` is just `map show`